# Thread safety of the icu::Transliterator::transliterate

Tags: c++, icu

Is it safe to call the icu::Transliterator::transliterate method of a single Transliterator object from multiple threads? In C++ implementation of ICU library.

I see that the method is constant, but I did not understand whether it can be called in a multi-threaded environment, because I didn't find any information about this in the documentation.

Comment: Does the documentation say it is threadsafe? If not (and this is true for almost all API's) then it is NOT threadsafe. Also constant doesn't mean it is threadsafe, you could still be reading a (member) variable that can be modified (non-atomically) by other threads. Const only means calling the function will not change the state of the object so it doesn't promise anything about threadsafety.

Comment: When dealing with 3rd party API's and multithreading I usually use an executor (thread + function queue) to interact with it ensuring all calls to the API are made from the same thread (I've encountered libraries with thread local storage and they break down when called from different threads). So using an executor will address both problems, only one call at a time and calls all happen from the same thread. (You will  need a library, executors are not part of the C++ standard yet : https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0443r12.html)